# Test React Form internal submit

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, user-interface, testing, react-testing-library

I have this component:

```
function Form() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const hanleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('submit', value);
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

and the following test:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "react-testing-library";
import Form from "./Form";

it("submits", () => {
  const onSubmit = jest.fn();
  const { getByText } = render(<Form />);
  fireEvent.click(getByText("Add"));
  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled(); // test fail with 0 called
});
```

I know I gotta to pass this mock function as prop.

But I'd like to know if exist a way to test internal function like `handleSubmit` without pass as prop?

I'm using react-testing-library.

Comment: all answers that I found it pass `onSubmit` as prop :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jest.spyOn(console, 'log')` and check the `handleSubmit` is triggered indirectly. In fact, `handleSubmit` should have some more meaningful logic, not just console.log(). We should test the meaningful logic. But for the code you posted, then only we can do is above.

You should test the behavior of the component rather than an implementation detail.

The behavior of the component is: when you trigger the event handler, some states may change, the component will re-render, UI structure change, assert UI changes.

The implementation detail is: assert some function is called or not. This makes test cases vulnerable.

Test behavior or function, you don't need to pay attention to implementation details, regardless of the implementation details, we only test the final result.

If your component is just a presentation component with no state, just perform a Snapshot test to check the UI hierarchy.

If there are states, you need to test different states of the component.

If the state is promoted to the parent, then you test the parent and the state of the child on the UI when the parent state changes

Passing the mock `onSubmit` as a prop is a simple and common way.

If you want to handle some logic in `Form` component and call the `onSubmit` function passed from parent component in the same time.

You should write it like this:

```js
const hanleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // some logic for Form component itself, you should test these logic when you test Form component rather than `props.onSubmit()`.
    console.log('submit', value);
    // Parent component only care about the submitted value.
    props?.onSubmit(value)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @slideshowp2.

Please, follow my original code 

https://gist.github.com/alexalannunes/841f7fd1f0967f3929262617d56fbbbd

Could you tell me something?
Thanks